# Automation for GUI desktop application with java framework

Tags: java, user-interface, selenium, automation, ui-automation

Lately i bumped into [selenuim](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)  for web automation which is wonderful tool , gives you the ability to record a test on the web browser and export it into java/c#/etc and modify it as you want in any Java IDE for example.

I know that selenium is only for Web .

Dose selenium got an extension / open source plug in to support desktop GUI application?
There is another framework that do that for desktop GUI application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you can do this

> another framework that do that for desktop GUI application

is by using [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). Since it uses image recognition technology
can be used across all desktop applications, also can be driven by *multiple languages*
and its *free*.

Just to be full this answer, I'll add that you can combine it with [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) and [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) like is [shown here](http://prezi.com/arubpcolpmzv/test-automation-using-sikuli-cucumber-and-jenkins/).

***Update***

> export scripts to Java

is not possible in this sense, since Sikuli scripts are written in Python scripting language and the scripts itself are run using the Jython interpreter (Java base implementation of Python language).
[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203381/how-to-export-sikuli-scripts-to-java)
and [this answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/166991).

Look at these resources *how-to*:

- [how-to-write-java-program-in-sikuli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473465/how-to-write-java-program-in-sikuli)
- [sikuli-java-insertion-dev](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html)
- [use SikuliX API in your JAVA programs](http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/030-java-dev.html)

Comment: will give it a try.
Dose sikuli is able to export the test to java code?

Comment: You can use Testmate to automate Java swing application for free
https://youtu.be/BQQdJ0V23GM

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [UiPath](http://uipath.com) can automate desktop, browser, remote desktops or java applications.

Unlike Selenium it has the [ability](https://github.com/UiPath/SDK/wiki/Java-screen-scraping) to get access to the internal object model of a java app (recognise the controls and elements you want to click, type, scrape). You can use it from code (SDK) or create automation directly from UiPath Studio.

Answer (score 2):

If you create your application using Swing, so you can test it with [FEST](https://code.google.com/p/fest/). But this lib is no longer supported and works wrong with Linux. There are some another non-free test tools for Swing and JavaFX but I've never used these tools and cannot say whether they good or not.

You can found something about test tools for JavaFX [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599724/gui-testing-framework-for-javafx-2). For Swing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79891/what-is-the-best-testing-tool-for-swing-based-applications).

Comment: Thanks but there are not swings application.